# Replace MAC address with UUID

Tags: linux, sed, scripting, regular-expression, mac-address

I am looking for a way to mask the client MAC address every time it appears in a logfile before using the logfile to present data to a customer (GDPR rules).

I can identify the MAC string using regex, but am unsure what the best way of masking is, since MD5 seems to be advised against as it's almost transparent!

I need a given MAC to always return the same mask/uuid since MACs will be coming in at various times and I need to track a given MAC as it goes through the system.

regex used is  `(?<=clientMac":\s")[A-Z0-9]{12}`

Ideally I'd like to use something simple like `sed` to make the substitution but I accept it may not be possible.

Comment: Your issue seems to be more a privacy thing and less a scripting problem, so it may be out of scope here. But if your concern is that the customer could test all possible MACs for their MD5: Sure, but why not hash over a concatenation of the MAC and some password you don't reveal to the customer? And yes, of course you can do the replacement with `sed`.

Comment: Thanks for replying :) You are referring to ‘salting’ I believe? Would it be possible to see an example of the sed syntax for using an external function like that? So far I have used it for simple reflex detection and replacement only.

Comment: Too long to fit into a comment, so I explained it in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested in the comment, here is an example how to perform such a substitution with `sed`. You used the /linux tag, so it should be safe to use GNU `sed` with its `e` flag for the `s` command:

```
sed -E 'h;s/.*clientMac":\s"([A-Z0-9]{12}).*/echo secretKey\1|md5sum/e;T
  G;s/(.*)\s*-\n(.*clientMac":\s")[A-Z0-9]{12}(.*)/\2\1\3/' logfile
```

Explanation:

- The `h` command saves the line to the hold space, so we can restore it after messing up the line (-;
- `s/.*clientMac":\s"([A-Z0-9]{12}).*/echo secretKey\1|md5sum/e` matches the whole line, putting the actual MAC in `()` to be reused in the replacement. The replacement forms the command to be executed: `echo`ing the MCA along with the "salt" and piping it into `md5sum`. The `e` flag makes `sed` execute this in the shell and putting the result in the buffer again
- `T` branches to the end of the script if no replacement was made. This is to print lines without MAC unmodified. Following lines are executed only if a replacement was made
- `G` appends the original line from the hold buffer, so now we have the `md5sum` output, a newline and the original line in the buffer
- `s/(.*)\s*-\n(.*clientMac":\s")[A-Z0-9]{12}(.*)/\2\1\3/` captures the MD5 in the first pair of `()`, the line before the MAC in the second and the rest of the line after the MAC in the third, thus `\2\1\3` replaces the MAC with the MD5

Comment: Thank you, nice solution using just sed!

Comment: Nice solution sed guru. Can you edit with command line turn to a sed script that might be more readable ?

Comment: I'm far from being an `sed` guru; maybe it's easier to write than to read, like it often happens with regular expressions. The whole magic mainly takes place in those two `s`ubstitute commands and putting it inside a script won't make it easier, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

The following `perl` script uses either the  [`Digest::MD5`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::MD5) or [`Digest::SHA`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::SHA) module to transform a MAC address to a hash, using a secret salt.   See the man pages of the modules for more details on them.  It's worth noting that Digest::SHA has several more algorithms to choose from.

The code is written to make it easy to choose a different hashing algorithm - uncomment one and comment out the others to choose whichever suits you best.  BTW, the output from the `_base64` versions of the functions is a little shorter then the `_hex` functions but look more like line-noise.

I simplified your provided regex (couldn't see any need for a look-behind). You may need to tweak that a bit to work with your input data....you didn't provide any sample so I just guessed.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

# choose one of the following digest modules:
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex md5_base64);
#use Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex sha256_base64);

use strict;

my $salt='secret salt phrase';

# store seen MAC addresses in a hash so we only have to calculate the digest
# for them once.  This speed optimisation is only useful if the input file
# is large AND any given MAC address may be seen many times.
my %macs=();

while(<>) {
  if (m/clientMac:\s*([A-Z0-9]{12})/i) {
    my $mac = $1;

    if (!defined($macs{$mac})) {
      # choose one of the following digest conversions:

      #my $uuid = sha256_hex($mac . $salt);
      #my $uuid = sha256_base64($mac . $salt);
      my $uuid = md5_hex($mac . $salt);
      #my $uuid = md5_base64($mac . $salt);

      $macs{$mac} = $uuid;
    };

    s/(clientMac:\s*)$mac/$1$macs{$mac}/gio;
  };
  print;
};
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much. I appreciate the answer and the simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative approach, sometimes I used simple line numbers as obfuscation value. This makes the output more compact and more readable.

Also, `awk` is a good tool when one needs to perform "smart" operations on a text file, having a more readable language than `sed`. The "smart" operation to perform in this case is avoid re-executing the obfuscation algorithm when any one MAC address is encountered more than once. This can speed up operations quite a lot if you have thousand of lines referring to a small number of MAC addresses.

In practice, consider the following script, which also handles possible multiple MAC addresses occurring on any one line, identifying and replacing each occurrence, and then prints a mapping table at the end:

```awk
awk -v pat='clientMac"\\s*"[[:xdigit:]]{12}' -v table='sort -k 1,1n | column -t' -- '
$0 ~ pat {
    for (i=1; i <= NF; i++)
        if (match($i, pat)) {
            if (!($i in cache))
                cache[$i]=NR "." i
            $i = "MAC:" cache[$i]
        }
}
1
END {
    print "---Table: "FILENAME"\nnum MAC" | table
    for (mac in cache)
        print cache[mac], mac | table
}
' file.log
```

The table at the end can be easily separated from the main output by an additional editing step, or by just making the command string in the `-v table=` argument redirect its output to a file, like in `-v table='sort -k 1,1n | column -t > table'`. It can also be removed altogether by just removing the entire `END{ … }` block.

As a variant, using a real encryption engine to compute obfuscation values and hence with no mapping table at the end:

```awk
awk -v pat='clientMac"\\s*"[[:xdigit:]]{12}' -v crypter='openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -pass file:mypassfile' -- '
$0 ~ pat {
    for (i=1; i <= NF; i++)
        if (match($i, pat)) {
            addr = cache[$i]
            if (addr == "") {
                "echo '\''" $i "'\'' | " crypter | getline addr
                cache[$i] = addr
            }
            $i = "MAC:" addr
        }
}
1
' file.log
```

Here I used `openssl` as encryption engine selecting its `aes-256-cbc` cipher (with also a base64-encoded output in order to be text-friendly), and making it read the encryption secret from a file named `mypassfile`.

Strings encrypted with a symmetric cipher (like `aes-256-cbc`) can be decrypted by knowing the secret used (the contents of `mypassfile`, which you want to keep for yourself), therefore they can be reversed. Also, since `openssl` uses a random salt by default, each run produces different values for the same input. Not using a salt (option `-nosalt`) would make `openssl` produce the same value for each run, so less secure, but on the other hand would produce shorter texts while still being encrypted.

The same `awk` script would work for other external commands instead of `openssl` by just replacing the command in the `-v crypter=` argument to `awk`, as long as the external command you choose can accept input from stdin and print output to stdout.

Strings hashed with algorithms like MD5 or SHA instead are one-way only (i.e. they can't be reversed), and always produce the same value for the same input, therefore you'd want to "salt" them so that the computed values produced in output can't just be searched over all possible MAC addresses. You might add a random "salt" as in the following slightly modified script:

```awk
awk -v pat='clientMac"\\s*"[[:xdigit:]]{12}' -v crypter='sha256sum' -- '
$0 ~ pat {
    for (i=1; i <= NF; i++)
        if (match($i, pat)) {
            addr = cache[$i]
            if (addr == "") {
                "(dd if=/dev/random bs=16 count=1 2>/dev/null; echo '\''" $i "'\'') | " crypter | getline addr
                cache[$i] = addr
            }
            $i = "MAC:" addr
        }
}
1
' file.log
```

This latter script uses a 16 bytes-long (pseudo-)random value as "salt", thus producing a different hash value on each run over the same data.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time tom post such a concise answer!